# how to remove sails js default log messages

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Please how to remove this default log messages that are displayed when "sails lift" that also written to my external log files :

```
info: Starting app...

debug: Deprecation warning: Support for `sails.config.sockets.onConnect` will be
 removed in an upcoming release. See the v0.11 migration guide for more informat
ion and alternate options.
info:
info:                .-..-.
info:
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.12.4             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------'
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info:
info: Server lifted in `E:\Orange\sailsJS_workspace\server`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.
debug: -------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Wed Nov 02 2016 12:03:45 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)
debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: -------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-log

Comment: @DaveNewton : sails doc can not help ... thank u

Comment: You mean you specifically want to disable *those* logs? You modify the Sails source code.

Comment: yes exactly @DaveNewton

Comment: You modify the Sails source.

Comment: Where i can modify this ? which file ? @DaveNewton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add:

```
noShip: true
```

To file: `config/log.js`

For other default log messages play with "level", it's documented in comments at beginning of file.

Answer (score 0):

Set `level:` to `silent` in the log.js

Ex:

```
module.exports.log = {
    custom: blahblahBlah,
    inspect: false
    level: 'info'
};
```